# Can we read the text in an image and print it using TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to read an image(png) and print the text in that image. I need to do this in Tensor Flow using Python. I did search a lot and tried many methods in tf library. But I could either print the tensor array or the shape. How can i convert that tensor array into a readable text that matches the content in an image. I am attaching the sample image here.

I could create the 'Test.txt' but that has all junk characters (displays like chinise/japanese characters). My goal is to read the image and print the content of the image  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' in the console or to a text file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image 

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['Test.png'])
reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(24300)
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8
depth_major = tf.reshape(tf.slice(record_bytes, [0], [24300]),[3, 90, 90])
result_uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init_op)

   coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

   result = sess.run(result_uint8image)
   image=record_bytes.eval()
   a=np.asarray(image)
   a.tofile('Test.txt')
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

[English Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkKoM.png)

Comment: Is your question whether TensorFlow has a prebuilt function to do this? then: no. If your question is whether you can build a model that tries to do this: then yes.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was looking for some prebuilt methods to achieve this. I am new to TensorFlow and may i know if there are any references to build such models to read and print the data?

Comment: The problem you're looking at is OCR - object character recognition. In a very basic form you can build a MNIST model - a model that predicts the numbers 1,2,..,9 in a handwritten form. https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners is a good start. The OCR problem can also get very tricky, as the picture gets more distorted, a more popular one is a benchmark where they predict french street names, taken from google maps.

Comment: try to build a simple MNIST model, then if still interested look into literature about OCR and CNN models

Comment: ok. I tried and could get result with tesseract-OCR and OpenCV. But i thought if we can d o it using TensorFlow too. I will start from MNIST example. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Use tesseract-OCR with Python implementation [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract)